# How to Export Images to Excel with asp.NET 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I am Export some data in EXCEL. now my client wants to export images in excel also.

Can anybody have any idea how can I export images with data in EXCEL.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't export images to Excel !!

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit flou. 
Is your source Excel and you want to Export data and images from Excel to an ASP.net application or is your source an ASP.NET and you want to export data into excel and create images(charts we call 'm) from the data? 
Or do your images have nothing to do with the Excel data itself?